# Is php-mysql: update column with different values depending on condition involving PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli, sql-update

I have a webform with the string variables `$participant1, participant2`, and `$winner` in php.When a form is posted it updates the columns `participant` and `winner` for two rows in `my_table`. The column type for `winner` is `BOOLEAN`.

Here is what my table currently looks like:

```
ID |Game |Participant | Winner
-------------------------------
1     1     John          NULL
2     1     Frank         NULL
```

The submitted variable `$winner` will be the name of either `participant` ('John' or 'Frank'). When it is submitted, I'd like for `1` to be set for which ever participant the string `$winner` matches. And `0` for the other participant.

i.e. if `$participant1 =='John' and $winner=='John'`
Then the table should look like:

```
ID |Game |Participant | Winner
-------------------------------
1     1     John          1
2     1     Frank         0
```

I can't seem to figure this part out.

I tried:

```
$participant1= mysqli_escape_string( $con, $params['participant1']);
$participant2= mysqli_escape_string( $con, $params['participant2']);
$Winner= mysqli_escape_string( $con, $params['Winner']);    

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE my_table SET Winner = IF('$Winner'=='$participant1',1,0) WHERE Participant ='$participant1');

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE my_table SET Winner = IF('$Winner'=='$participant2',1,0) WHERE Participant ='$participant2'");
```

`Winner` still shows `NULL` afterwards. Is there a primarily MySQL way to do this?

Comment: mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE my_table SET Winner = '". $Winner==$participant1 ? 0 : 1 ."' WHERE Participant ='$participant1' " );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey replace == with =

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE my_table SET Winner = IF('$Winner'='$participant1',1,0) WHERE Participant ='$participant1'");
```

Tested Code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$a='John';
$b='Mary';

$w='John';

mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE myguest SET Winner = IF('$a'='$w',1,0) WHERE FirstName ='$a'");
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE myguest SET Winner = IF('$b'='$w',1,0) WHERE FirstName ='$b'");
```